# Why the wavefunction of a set of non-interacting particles is a product of the individual wavefunctions of each particle in the set?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Quantum mechanics, before we get to Slater determinants and all that, it is said that many-particle wavefunction for the case of non-interacting particles is just a product of all the particles' individual wavefunctions. There is certainly a good reasoning to assume so: since the particles are independent, they are statistically uncorrelated.

In statistics, for several uncorrelated events, the total probability is the product of every event's probability. So, in that sense, product of wavefunctions seems like a very reasonable step. What I want to ask is: is it okay to just assume that? I think in statistics it is just one of the basic principles, and it is not to be proven. Is this the case here as well? Or is there a way to show mathematically that the many-particle wavefunction is the product?

Comment: See the second [postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Postulates_of_quantum_mechanics).

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly: how would particles become entangled without having interacted?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Antisymmetry can do that: $\phi_a(x)\phi_b(y)\to \phi_a(x)\phi_b(y)-\phi_b(x)\phi_a(y)$.  This also works for symmetric states of course.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: Makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

If the particles are not interacting then
\begin{align}
H=H_1+H_2:= H_1\otimes \mathbb{I}+\mathbb{I}\otimes H_2
\end{align}
and $\vert \psi_1\rangle\vert\phi_2\rangle$ is immediately an eigenstate with energy $E=E_1+E_2$.  Alternatively, by separation of variables, $H_1$ acts only on $x_1$ and $H_2$ on $x_2$ so that $\Psi(x_1,x_2)=\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)$ is also immediately a solution:
\begin{align}
\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\partial^2_{x_1}+V(x_1)\right)\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)
&= H_1\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)=E_1\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\, ,\\
\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\partial^2_{x_2}+V(x_2)\right)\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)&=
H_2\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)=E_2\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\, ,\\
(H_1+H_2)\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)&=(E_1+E_2)\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)=E\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your response! Ok, I can see how to get from the two separate equations to the full one. But how to do it the other way around? Because we start with the total one, and then, using all we know, we decompose this equation into one-particle equations.

Comment: Just use the usual separation of variables.  Start with $H=H_1+H_2$, assume $\Psi(x_1,x_2)=\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)$, and separate the pieces in $x_1$ and $x_2$ on each side of an equal sign.

Comment: Then both equations have to be equal to a constant, right? What is that constant?

Comment: I’ve done enough.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero then, we just assume that the total state is the product of the states of each particle?

Comment: @Invenietis yes.  If they are not interacting then basically separation of variables in $x_1$ and $x_2$ will work in he same way as it does in separating any other variables: this results in a product state.